# I bought a LEGO set from a yardsale and have no instructions, box or date

Tags: set-identification, city

I want to find out what LEGO set I have so I can get some instructions for it. I'll add some pictures of the pieces as that's about all I can do.

[image: Some of the pieces to the lego set.]

I hope this is enough for someone to be to figure out which set this is.

Comment: For some reason it took the rest of my pictures away. Tell me if you need more and I'll try to add them.

Comment: Does the raft have any decals or printing on it?

Comment: No it is just all blue except for the spot in the middle.

Comment: Ahh, it's blue - the picture makes it look black.  Dark blue right?

Answer (score 3):

If the boat is dark blue then the set is almost certain to be set [60069-1 **Swamp Police Station**](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60069-1) since [according to Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=62812&in=S) it is the only occurrence of the boat (part [62812 Boat, Rubber Raft, Large](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62812)) in dark blue.

The presence of the bars (parts [92586](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92589&idColor=86) and [60621](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60621&idColor=86)) with white frame[s] (part [60596](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60596&idColor=1)) and light bluish gray radar disk thingy (part [4285b](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4285b&idColor=86)) confirm this theory.

However, I was unable to identify the large black piece near the top-left of your picture, or find something similar to it in the [set's inventory](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=60069-1).  Is this a single piece?  If so it is probably not part of the rest of the set.

Comment: I don't know what that piece is. From what I've seen that's the only one I got in the container. But thank you very much for finding out which set it is. I am really excited to find some instructions and build this. Building is something I love And I love lego so this really made my day! Thanks again!

Comment: @EPICPOPTARTNINJA  That's odd, I'm pretty sure it doesn't belong with the rest of the set.  Now you have me curious!  Can you find a part number on it?  (BTW, if this answer has sufficiently answered your question, you can [mark it as accepted](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) with the green checkmark under the voting buttons.)